# unable to render with array buffers in Java with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vertex-buffer, vertex-array-object

I'm attempting to learn how to program in OpenGL the modern way, using vertex array/vertex buffer objects. I'm using the tutorials on the LWJGL wiki right now, and even if I copy & paste the tutorial code, I get a window with the background colour set properly but no shape rendered on top of it. The tutorial page shows a screenshot with a white rectangle rendered over the background. Is this a common issue, or is there any way I can get further information on my error?

**Edit: using shaders and putting some colour on the vertices fixes the problem. I'm not posting this as an answer quite yet though, because I'm assuming the tutorial code was intended to work without the use of shaders. (which are in a later portion of the tutorial)**

This is the code on the tutorial page:

```
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class TheQuadExampleDrawArrays {
    // Entry point for the application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TheQuadExampleDrawArrays();
    }

    // Setup variables
    private final String WINDOW_TITLE = "The Quad: glDrawArrays";
    private final int WIDTH = 320;
    private final int HEIGHT = 240;
    // Quad variables
    private int vaoId = 0;
    private int vboId = 0;
    private int vertexCount = 0;

    public TheQuadExampleDrawArrays() {
        // Initialize OpenGL (Display)
        this.setupOpenGL();

        this.setupQuad();

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            // Do a single loop (logic/render)
            this.loopCycle();

            // Force a maximum FPS of about 60
            Display.sync(60);
            // Let the CPU synchronize with the GPU if GPU is tagging behind
            Display.update();
        }

        // Destroy OpenGL (Display)
        this.destroyOpenGL();
    }

    public void setupOpenGL() {
        // Setup an OpenGL context with API version 3.2
        try {
            PixelFormat pixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
            ContextAttribs contextAtrributes = new ContextAttribs(3, 2)
                .withForwardCompatible(true)
                .withProfileCore(true);

            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.setTitle(WINDOW_TITLE);
            Display.create(pixelFormat, contextAtrributes);

            GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // Setup an XNA like background color
        GL11.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.6f, 0.9f, 0f);

        // Map the internal OpenGL coordinate system to the entire screen
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        this.exitOnGLError("Error in setupOpenGL");
    }

    public void setupQuad() {       
        // OpenGL expects vertices to be defined counter clockwise by default
        float[] vertices = {
                // Left bottom triangle
                -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                // Right top triangle
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
                -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f
        };
        // Sending data to OpenGL requires the usage of (flipped) byte buffers
        FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
        verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
        verticesBuffer.flip();

        vertexCount = 6;

        // Create a new Vertex Array Object in memory and select it (bind)
        // A VAO can have up to 16 attributes (VBO's) assigned to it by default
        vaoId = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

        // Create a new Vertex Buffer Object in memory and select it (bind)
        // A VBO is a collection of Vectors which in this case resemble the location of each vertex.
        vboId = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        // Put the VBO in the attributes list at index 0
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        // Deselect (bind to 0) the VBO
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Deselect (bind to 0) the VAO
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        this.exitOnGLError("Error in setupQuad");
    }

    public void loopCycle() {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Bind to the VAO that has all the information about the quad vertices
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Draw the vertices
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        // Put everything back to default (deselect)
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        this.exitOnGLError("Error in loopCycle");
    }

    public void destroyOpenGL() {       
        // Disable the VBO index from the VAO attributes list
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Delete the VBO
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vboId);

        // Delete the VAO
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoId);

        Display.destroy();
    }

    public void exitOnGLError(String errorMessage) {
        int errorValue = GL11.glGetError();

        if (errorValue != GL11.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            String errorString = GLU.gluErrorString(errorValue);
            System.err.println("ERROR - " + errorMessage + ": " + errorString);

            if (Display.isCreated()) Display.destroy();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your shaders? With the core profile, you need to supply your own shader progam written in GLSL.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Is there a different way I can set that up so I don't need to? I tried removing .withProfileCore(true) to no avail. The tutorial hasn't mention anything about custom shaders at this point.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly LWJGL handles context creation. Removing `withForwardCompatible(true)` and `withProfileCore(true)` would seem to make sense. Or maybe change the values to `false`.

Comment: Unfortunately doing neither of those things seems to fix my problem. I'll try looking at another tutorial in a while and comparing differences though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but since the Z coordinate is 0 on all of your vertices shouldn't it be at the exact position of the near clipping plane and thus not render because it is out of range, so you should try moving the vertices back along the Z axis and it should theoretically render.

Comment: No. As far as one can tell from the code given, this is directly drawing in clip space, and clip space z=0 is right in the middle of the viewing frustum.